# Login on startup, UITabBarViewController loading issue, iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I implemented login on app startup by switching `window.rootViewController` the way it is described here: http://sweettutos.com/2014/01/08/present-a-login-screen-before-the-tab-bar-controller-in-a-uitabbarcontroller-based-app/

Somehow, the `UIViewController` that is shown after successful login is not loaded properly and I see nothing in its UITableView:

[image]

When I click any selection of the tab bar at the top, things are shown properly and everything starts working, so the issue is only this first screen without any results:

[image]

The very important point here is that after login on startup is done once, and next times the app starts right away from the main page upon just reloading the app (Command + R in Xcode), the main page `is shown correctly right away`.

So, my question is what is the difference between the two cases of controller's loading? Why it is not loaded correctly after logging in? I would assume that reloading vs logging in should give the same results.

The controller (main page, the table) loads the data when it receives notification from the local storage that retrieves data from a web server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set selected index of tabbar when view appears.

```
[myTabBar setSelectedItem:myTabBarItem];
```

Comment: Yep. The solution is that simple. I set `self.segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex = 0;
    [self switchMonthAction:self.segmentedControl];` in `viewWillAppear` and it starts working. Do you know why it is loaded properly when login is not shown? Some synchronization difference? I mean `viewDidLoad` is called prematurely, or smth else?

Comment: I would expect both cases (loading after logging in vs restarting the app) to be equivalent...

Answer (score 0):

I guess that you put load data in `viewDidload`. So in case login: You must go login and put into to go this screen. After login you just dismiss and don't reload data. In case you go straight: you have token there so data have loaded.

So solution here is: after login you post notification to tabbar and tabbar will call function reload data.

Comment: Nope, I have very little in `viewDidLoad`, no data loading. It is actually the other way round: everything that is set up in `viewDidLoad` is rendered properly: `titleView`, its tintColor, etc. My local datastore sends a notification upon loading the data and maybe the controller is somehow missing it, I do not know. But the first answer solved the issue. I still do not quite understand why.